# Argument not optional VBA Count

Tags: excel, vba

I have an action tracker spreadsheet with some VBA, whose function is to timestamp whenever I update a row.

I removed three columns from the spreadsheet. Of course, the timestamps were still appearing in column J as before, but I now want them to appear in column G.

When I went to update the code to fix that, I got an "argument not optional" error, highlighting the Count.

Below is the code that gets me the error. I updated it to change the range from A1:I9999 to A1:F9999; and I changed the offset from 0, 10 to 0, 7.

Other than that I made no changes to the code, which was working fine before I removed the columns and edited the VBA. Can you help me?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count = 1 Then
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:F9999")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Target.Offset(0, 7 - Target.Column()) = Now()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me. Do you have any other code?

Comment: if the idea is to have a timestamp in column G, then ´cells(target.row,"G")=now()´, should do the job

Comment: What is `Count` supposed to be counting? Cells? Rows? Columns? Charts? You see the problem - VBA is having to guess and isn't guessing what you intend...

Comment: @CindyMeister: Nothing worng with that line. It will never count rows or columns or charts. If you see the declarion it says `ByVal Target As Range` ;)

Comment: mega, avoid using `.Count`. In excel 2007+, better to use `.CountLarge`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, but what is the `Range`? We can't know that. In the Help for `Range.Count` there's no initimation what the default might be, or under what circumstances what kind of object is counted. All the examples specify the object to be counted.

Comment: @CindyMeister: "Target.Count" refers to "Target's", `Cells.Count`. That is default. To count Columns, you would say `Target.Columns.Count` For cells you do not need to mention it..

Comment: Seconded, the code also works fine for me. I even recreated your scenario (removing 3 columns & updating the code) and it still works fine. Could you please paste a screenshot of your Worksheet and also let us know if the error occurs only when updating some cells, or does it affect any cell in A1:F9999 range?